# Mysql. a multiple-column index exists on col1 and col2, what's the index will be use?

Tags: mysql, indexing, query-performance

mysql 8.0.21

```
CREATE TABLE test (
    id         INT NOT NULL,
    last_name  CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    first_name CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    INDEX name (last_name,first_name)
);
```

sql is:  `select * from test where last_name between 'james' and 'jones' and first_name = 'M'`

what's the index will be use in fact, **(last_name, first_name)** or **just part of the 2-column index**?

ref: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/multiple-column-indexes.html

Comment: Use [`explain`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/explain.html) and you can find out by yourself.

Comment: There is no `INDEX(last_name)` in your table definition, so your question should be rephrased to ask whether it will use just part of the 2-column index.

Answer (score 2):

Your index on `(last_name, first_name)` happens to be a [covering index](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/glossary.html#glos_covering_index).  That is, the database server can satisfy your entire query from the index without referring back to the table. That's generally a performance win. So the answer to your specific question is, **Yes** your two-column index will be used. (Your PK `id` value is automatically part of the index.)

Is that the perfect index, for the best possible handling of your specific query?

```
  WHERE first_name = constant AND last_name BETWEEN whatever AND whatelse
```

**No**, it is not. The perfect index for that query will be `(first_name, last_name)`. That index lets the server satisfy your query with an [index range scan](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/glossary.html#glos_covering_index). It finds the constant `first_name` and the first matching `last_name`, then scans through the index to the last matching `last_name`. That's quick, even on a huge table.

And @gmb is correct. Put [`EXPLAIN` or `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` right before your `SELECT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/explain.html) and the database server will give you information about how it satisfies your query.

Study this great material by Marcus Winand:  https://use-the-index-luke.com/

Comment: If another column is added to the table, the index will no longer be "covering".  However, that index will continue to use ICP (Index Condition Pushdown) ("Using index condition"), which has some benefit.

Answer (score 0):

This would be the optimal index to have for *that* `SELECT`:

```
INDEX(first_name, last_name)
```

Probably you would want both:

```
INDEX(last_name, first_name)
INDEX(first_name, last_name)
```

Do not also include `INDEX(last_name)` or `INDEX(first_name)`; they confuse the Optimizer.  See http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/find_nearest_in_mysql#bounding_box

When building an optimal index, *start* with any column being tested with '='.  (That is `first_name` in your example.)  More:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql